# Displaying list of items /w respect to nesting

Tags: python, recursion, tree, comments, structure

I have list of comments which have attrs: `pk` (primary key), `parent_pk` (primary key of parent) and others... I want to display them w/ respect to nesting — if comment has children, display comment and then children which are indented more. Comment is child of other comment when it's `pk` is the same as other comments' `parent_pk`.

I will originally implement it in my Django blog, but first I want to learn how-to. That's why, for the sake of simplicity, I have created CLI app. I know that there are working-ready solutions out there, but I want to learn to do it myself. :)

This is my code for now:

```
class Comment(object):
    def __init__(self, pk, parent_pk, content):
        self.pk = pk
        self.parent_pk = parent_pk
        self.content = content

    def has_children(self, comments):
        for comment in comments:
            if self.pk == comment.parent_pk:
                return True
        return False

    def get_children(self, comments):
        children = []
        for comment in comments:
            if self.pk == comment.parent_pk:
                children.append(comment)
        return children


def print_nested(comments, level=0):
    def to_whitespaces(level):
        if level == 0:
            return ""
        else:
            return " " * (level * 2)

    for comment in comments:
        print to_whitespaces(level) + comment.content
        if comment.has_children(comments):
            print_nested(comment.get_children(comments), level + 1)
            comments.pop(0)

comments = [
    Comment(1, None, "foo"),
    Comment(2, 1, "foo bar"),
    Comment(3, None, "spam"),
    Comment(4, 3, "spam cheese"),
    Comment(5, 4, "spam cheese monty"),
    Comment(6, None, "muse"),
]

print_nested(comments)
```

[Here's it on Sprunge.us (w/ syntax).](http://sprunge.us/AIVb?py)

Expected result:

```
foo
  foo bar
spam
  spam cheese
    spam cheese monty
muse
```

Actual result:

```
foo
  foo bar
spam
  spam cheese
spam cheese monty
muse
```

As you can see, `spam cheese monty` isn't indented at all. Any ideas why's that? How would you implement it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you recursively call `print_nested` you only call it with the elements that are children of the current element.

So wen you call `print_nested` for the children of `spam`, you get only `spam cheese`.

That means that when you call `get_children` on `spam cheese`, there are no elements in the `comments` list you pass it, so `spam cheese monty` doesn't get indented because it is only encountered as a member of the outermost call to `print_nested`.

If you want to maintain the current structure of your script, you need to  make `get_children` recursive, so it finds the children of the children ad infinitum.

A better way would be to build a real tree out of the comments, where you can actually look up parent comments without doing a list traversal.

A simple method that works for your example and can easily be converted to use a tree instead of a list:

```
class Comment(object):
    def __init__(self, pk, parent_pk, content):
        self.pk = pk
        self.parent_pk = parent_pk
        self.content = content

    def depth(self):
        depth = 0
        comment = self
        # this is just a recursive lookup converted to iterative
        while comment.parent_pk:
            # replace the array indexing with traversing up a tree
            comment = comments[comment.parent_pk - 1]
            depth += 1
        return depth

def print_nested(comments):
    for comment in comments:
        print comment.depth() * 2 * " " + comment.content

comments = [
    Comment(1, None, "foo"),
    Comment(2, 1, "foo bar"),
    Comment(3, None, "spam"),
    Comment(4, 3, "spam cheese"),
    Comment(5, 4, "spam cheese monty"),
    Comment(6, None, "muse"),
]

print_nested(comments)
```

Comment: Wow, this is truly awesome! I can't quite understand... 1. Instead of doing recursion in printing function, we create new method for `Comment` which goes through all comments in `comments` list (little strange that you don't pass it as argument to `depth()` method) and recursively finds comment's depth? 2. Will this solution work if primary keys will be messed-up (any order)?

Comment: @daGrevis As I mention in the post and comments, you should build a tree out of the comments and use that data structure to find parents. That will remove the sensitivity to the order of the comments in the list. I just didn't write that part for you since I could illustrate the general method of calculating depth with your list since pks and indexes happen to correlate.

Answer (score 1):

you just need a recursive function which checks the children and prints them:

```
class Comment(object):
    def __init__(self, pk, parent_pk, content):
        self.pk = pk
        self.parent_pk = parent_pk
        self.content = content



def print_nested(comments,pk=None,level=0):
    for comment in comments:
        if comment.parent_pk==pk:
            print ' ' * (level * 2), comment.content
            print_nested(comments,comment.pk,level+1)

comments = [
    Comment(101, None, "foo"),
    Comment(201, 101, "foo bar"),
    Comment(301, None, "spam"),
    Comment(415, 301, "spam cheese"),
    Comment(505, 415, "spam cheese monty"),
    Comment(622, None, "muse"),
]

print_nested(comments)
```

Comment: This requires you to look through the whole list of comments for every comment, giving it O(n^2) complexity. The general method I use in my answer can easily be improved to give O(n) performance.

Answer (score 0):

After you display Comment(4, 3, "spam cheese"), which happens as a child of Comment(3, None, "spam"),
you get it pop-ed out of comments. So when you process Comment(5, 4, "spam cheese monty"), the parent "pk" is missing, thus result is displayed as root

Comment: Did you try removing the `pop`? It still doesn't work correctly.

Comment: After removing the `pop` — http://pastie.org/5058188 . I put it there because else all children are always printed out anyway.